# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't boot after fresh installation

Tags: installation, 12.10

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 and everything went fine but after restart it doesn't load. It is the only OS on my HDD.

Why doesn't Ubuntu load after installation?

Comment: Could you be a li'l more specific as to where it stops loading, like which screen? The Grub (OS selection menu)? or after the grub?  And a li'l more details about your hardware specifications, especially if you have any graphics cards and such.

Answer (score 0):

The installation works perfectly fine. After the installation it says it needs to restart and then it just doesn't load. It is stuck on the ubuntu purple screen.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button on your question to add the above information instead of adding it as an answer. It'd be great if you could do that and delete this answer.